# Join Syntax with loop to left table and list to the columns

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have those 3 tables

```
Warehouse

Id  name        
1   Warehouse 1     
2   Warehouse 2     


Items

Id  description     
1   Item 1      
2   Item 2      
3   Item 3



itemmovement

itemid     qtyin    qtyout  warehouseid
1            2                   1
1                      1         1
1            2                   2
2            1                   1
2            3                   1
2                      1         1
2            1                   2


Result      
ItemId  SumQuantityWarehouse1   SumQuantityWarehouse2
1              1                         2
2              3                         1
3              0                         0
```

I need the result to sum up sum(qtyin)-sum(qtyout) with respect to itemid and warehouseid , by listing all the warehouses in columns with the quantities 
of each item as shown in the result

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The tables warehouse and items seem unnecessary to the question since you aren't using them in desired result?

Comment: Yes P.Salmon in my query i will use it but it is just to show the item id to which table refers and the warehouseid to which table refers . in my query i will you them , but not to make it complicated i made the result to be clear and easy so that i can get an answer. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The only practical way to achieve this in MySQL is by using a stored procedure to build a dynamic query based on the list of warehouses. The query has to use conditional aggregation to build the result table. For your sample data, the query that is built looks like this:

```
SELECT i.Id
     , SUM(CASE WHEN m.warehouseID=1 THEN COALESCE(m.qtyin, 0) - COALESCE(m.qtyout, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS `SUMWarehouse 1`
     , SUM(CASE WHEN m.warehouseID=2 THEN COALESCE(m.qtyin, 0) - COALESCE(m.qtyout, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS `SUMWarehouse 2`
FROM items i 
LEFT JOIN itemmovement m ON m.itemid = i.Id
GROUP BY Id
```

Here is the procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS stocktake //
CREATE PROCEDURE stocktake()
BEGIN
  DECLARE wid INT;
  DECLARE wname VARCHAR(20);
  DECLARE query TEXT DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE whouse_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Id, name FROM warehouse;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
  OPEN whouse_cursor;
  SET @query = 'SELECT i.Id';
get_whouse: LOOP
  FETCH whouse_cursor INTO wid, wname;
  IF finished = 1 THEN 
    LEAVE get_whouse;
  END IF;
  SET @query = CONCAT(@query, ', SUM(CASE WHEN m.warehouseID=', wid, ' THEN COALESCE(m.qtyin, 0) - COALESCE(m.qtyout, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS `', wname, '`');
  END LOOP get_whouse;
  SET @query = CONCAT(@query, ' FROM items i LEFT JOIN itemmovement m ON m.itemid = i.Id');
  SET @query = CONCAT(@query, ' GROUP BY Id');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

And the output for your sample data:

```
Id  Warehouse 1     Warehouse 2
1   1               2
2   3               1
3   0               0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=166399560d8382a24f8f85871171a039)

[Alternate demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9ab429385629563f63f22d79431fd403) showing the procedure working with 5 warehouses.

Comment: What if i have 50 warehouses ? , what i'm thinking of is that if it is possible to get all the warehouse id from the table warehouse , and use a syntax that loops through those id's into the table of the itemmovement and extract the result

Comment: @Moussa this procedure will work for as many warehouses as you have because that's exactly what it does. Here's an example with it expanded to 3 warehouses: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=716a4d12367fc3afc6931835819a65c1

Comment: But this doesn't work for mysql database ... syntax problem @Nick

Comment: @Moussa sorry about that - I tested on MariaDB which doesn't have MySQLs problem with using local variables in PREPARE statements. I've edited my post with a version that will compile on MySQL too

Comment: @Moussa did the change help? If not, could you provide more information to help solve the problem?

Comment: Dear Nick , still not working , if you select Mysql 8.0 instead of the MariaDb it will show you error in code .

Comment: @Moussa apologies again, somehow I linked to the MariaDB version again. I've fixed the links to point to a MySQL 8.0 version that is working.

Comment: How is it possible  to call the procedure from a php file and show the result as needed @Nick

Comment: @Moussa hard to say without knowing your environment but something like `$sql = "call stocktake()"; $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { print_r($row); }`

Comment: i'm using Mysql not mysqli, if possible to assist me with that ,

 while($row = mysql_fetch_row($runprocedure)){
   for($i=0;$i<=6;$i++){
    echo "<th>".$row[$i]."</th>";
   }
instead of 6 i need to put the count(columns)
so that i can add brake line, instead of fixed number in the loop (6) &Nick

Comment: @Moussa I can't really solve that problem in comments. I think I have answered the question you originally posted, it's now time to close this one (preferably by accepting the answer) and post a new one to deal with the application side.